# Laravel 5.6 pagination doenst work

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. This is the error I get.

My controller:

```
$products = Product::inRandomOrder()->take(12)->paginate(5);
  return view('shop')->with([
       'products' => $products,
       'categories' => $categories,
       'categoryName' => $categoryName,
      ]);
```

My view :

```
{{ $products->links() }}
```

Everywhere I look for a solution or similar error it says that the way I have it is correct. But I keep getting the same error very frustrating. If my code or question is not clear enough please tell me I will add some code or my question.
Thanks

Comment: What does `dd(get_class($products))` give you before returning the view? Calling `paginate()` _should_ give you a `LengthAwarePaginator` instance.

Comment: I am sorry for this question i solved it myself already.

Comment: if(request()->category){
         $products = Product::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
         $query->where('slug', request()->category);
      })->get();
is what i had, when I removed the ->get() it worked

Comment: Yeah, it helps to post the actual code. `get()` will return a plain ol’ `Collection` as found.